# Check only for weekday values and color using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below VBA code that will color values in col "M" if it is greater than 1 and have the text "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)".

What I want to do is:

1. I have dates in col K and this code should run only on weekday dates and not on weekend dates.
2. I need to add additional text along with "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)", let's say "Text 2" , "Text 3". So, if col P has either "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)" or "Text 2" or "Text 3", the coloring should happen.(It would be great if it is possible to use wildcards here)
3. This code should run only in sheet "Latency"

   ```
   Sub LatencyMarker()
   Dim r As Long
   Dim m As Long
   On Error GoTo ExitHere:
   m = Range("M:P").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For r = 1 To m
       If Range("P" & r) = "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)" Then
           If Range("M" & r) >= 1 Then
               Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
           Else
               Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
           End If
       End If
   Next r

   ExitHere:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: _"and doesn't have the text "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)"_: actually your code is doing the opposite with `If Range("P" & r) = "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)" Then`. You may want to reword your narrative or your code and add some examples of desired behavior

Comment: Oops!! Sorry..edited the OP

Answer (score 0):

Pesky Latency sheet not cooperating again? If I understood everything you said above correctly then the following code should do the trick:

```
Sub LatencyMarker()
Dim targetWS As Worksheet
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim dataArr() As Variant
Dim rowCounter As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set targetWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Latency")
Set dataRange = targetWS.Range("A1:" & targetWS.Range(targetWS.UsedRange.address)(targetWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count, targetWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
Set dataArr = dataRange

For rowCounter = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
    If Weekday(dataArr(rowCounter, 11), vbMonday) <= 5 Then
        If dataArr(rowCounter, 16) = "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)" Or dataArr(rowCounter, 16) = "Text 2" Or dataArr(rowCounter, 16) = "Text 3" Then
            If dataArr(rowCounter, 13) >= 1 Then
                dataRange(rowcoumter, 13).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                dataRange(rowcoumter, 13).Font.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

ExitHere:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Couple things- I converted most of your range data manipulation to array data and renamed a few of your variables to be more clear-

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I'm getting an error message here - `Set dataArr = dataRange`  - Can't assign to array

Comment: Hi @stackmark , oops, remove the 'Set' in that line and should be all set.

Comment: Variable not defined error in `dataRange(rowcoumter, 13).Font.ColorIndex = 3`

Comment: Ahh yes, typo in rowCounter- should be `dataRange(rowCounter, 13).Font.ColorIndex = 3` ... a lesson for all in the value of `Option Explicit`!

Comment: @TheSilkCode, it's funny you are always advising everybody about the benefit of using `Option Explicit` but never use it in your codes!

Comment: @user3598756 , I know.. I have one module that I use to test and trouble-shoot code without `Option Explicit` incase I need to use a new variable half way through or something and don't want to have to restart the whole procedure- I am lucky it was in a comment and not an answer otherwise I would down vote myself relentlessly!

Comment: error in `Set dataRange = targetWS.Range("A1:" & targetWS.Range(targetWS.UsedRange.Address)(targetWS.UsedRange.Rows.count, targetWS.UsedRange.Columns.count))`  - Method 'range' of object '_worksheet' failed

Comment: Whoops- should be: `Set dataRange = targetWS.Range("A1:" & targetWS.Range(targetWS.UsedRange.Address)(targetWS.UsedRang‌​e.Rows.count, targetWS.UsedRange.Columns.count).address)`

Comment: Type mismatch error in `If Weekday(dataArr(rowCounter, 11), vbMonday) <= 5 Then` ..I have the proper date format (along with time) - "11/6/2016 23:55"

Comment: Hmm- is the data in `dataArr(rowCounter, 11)` populated and formatted? I would confirm that first, and then the other thing it could be running into is an unexpected data type in dataArr- you could add an explicit date conversion to the code to avoid any possible data type mismatches if that is what is causing the error.. would be as follows: `If Weekday(cdate(dataArr(rowCounter, 11)), vbMonday) <= 5 Then`

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong here...I use the same date ranges for other functions and it works fine...